# How to split comma separated cell values in a list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I hope you are doing well!

Code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Grade.xlsx')
df = df.loc[df['Current year'] =="Final Year"]
Num = df['Available Number'].values
```

Sample data:

```
Sr no.     Name     Current Year     City      Available Number 
1          joe       First Year      NY        125,869,589,852
2          mike      Final Year      MI        586
3          Ross      Final Year      NY        589,639,741
4          juli      Second Year     NY        869,253
```

Now my code copied value "586"(row2) and "589,639,741"(row3) in variable. But I want to covert those values in list(list of integers) and then later I want to iterate in for loop.

I want some thing like this:

```
list1 = [586]
list2 = [589,639,741]
```

I don't know how to separate those values and convert it in list.
If anyone here can help me? I started learning pandas recently. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a loop to convert the strings into list of int:

```
df['Available Number'] = df['Available Number'] \
                             .apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split(',')])
```

Output:

```
   Sr no.  Name Current Year City      Available Number
0       1   joe   First Year   NY  [125, 869, 589, 852]
1       2  mike   Final Year   MI                 [586]
2       3  Ross   Final Year   NY       [589, 639, 741]
3       4  juli  Second Year   NY            [869, 253]
```

Comment: I get error 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You already have a list??? What is the output of `type(df.at[0, 'Available Number'])
`?

Comment: The output is str

Comment: In your `Available Number`  column, one or more rows are not strings. To detect them, use this code: `df[df['Available Number'].apply(lambda x: not isinstance(x, str))]
`. The output is the *corrupted* rows

Comment: Yes Some of them are integers and some of them are str. So I want to convert the one which are str in integer list. By spliting them by ','(Comma seprated)